# responsive Hero-Image not working on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, web, background-image

I have the following Problem with my website:

I have a hero-section with a background image. It covers the background and uses `background-attachmend: fixed`. This works and looks pretty nice on my desktop.

Whereas on my iPhone the background is very blurred and the background is not fixed. If I change it to default, `background-attachmend: scroll`, then the background shows the right part of the picture with good quality.

If the background is fixed, the background is sometimes completely black on iPhone, depending if I use `background-size: cover` or not.

I know that iOS does not like fixed backgrounds but there has to be a way to fix this right?

Hope you can help me!

---

Edit:
My Css code for my `<section>` "home"

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #151515;
background-image: url(../images/titelbild-skydance.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom 100%;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
min-height: 804px;
position: relative;
```

Comment: Hi. Can you show the code you've attempted so far on this please?

Comment: Edited it, thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940497/background-image-is-over-zoomed-and-not-clearly-visible-in-iphone-browser/74948435#74948435 Here is my detailed explanation how I solved it.

Comment: Here is the detailed explanation how I solved it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940497/background-image-is-over-zoomed-and-not-clearly-visible-in-iphone-browser/74948435#74948435

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940497/background-image-is-over-zoomed-and-not-clearly-visible-in-iphone-browser/74948435#74948435 Here is the detailed explanation how I solved it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940497/background-image-is-over-zoomed-and-not-clearly-visible-in-iphone-browser Here is the detailed explanation how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

For a responsive `background-image` use the following **CSS** for your `<section>` tag:

```
section {

min-height: 800px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url("../images/titelbild-skydance.jpg");
background-position: 0%, 0%, 50%, 50%;
background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
background-size: auto, cover;

}
```

Comment: That did not help, sry. The background now is not fixed, not on mobile not on desktop.The position of some elements changed, too.

Comment: Have you tried using media queries for this? Changing the image dependent on the window size? that way you can keep both images (mobile / desktop) fixed and where you want them?

Comment: The image size is not the problem i guess, its size changes. Looking at an iPhone in Chrome DevTools shows a perfect behavior. But live on the website, the iPhone doesn't use background-attachment:fixed and this causes the ugly blur or the lose of the image at all.